# unicorn: do I need to disconnect from database in before_fork block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, unicorn

[There](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-optimize-unicorn-workers-in-a-ruby-on-rails-app?comment=6973) is a comment that explains why you don't need to (and shouldn't) disconnect from DB and Redis in before_fork:

> By disconnecting in before_fork, you are closing the connection at the parent process every time you spawn a child, which is only needed once - you're beating a dead horse. Connection handling is a child's concern (after_fork) rather than a parent's concern (before_fork).
>
> ActiveRecord's connection pool is now keyed by `Process.pid`, so it's always safe to call `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` in after_fork - the connection will never be shared with the parent, no need to disconnect at the master anyway.
>
> On Unicorn, the master process is a singleton and can be used in many ways - spawn a thread and run EventMachine loop inside it to run scheduled / background jobs, etc. And there it's useful to keep the AR connection open. Only main thread will be inherited to a child (on linux systems at least) so it's safe to have threads.

Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

It definitely isn't required, but I prefer to do it anyway - we run a ton of application servers and if we didn't disconnect the master process from the DB we'd be holding a lot of connections open for no reason.